# How to convert SDF file database to SqlServer Database

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce

I have a SDF file database (SQLCESerer Compact 3.5), I want to convert it to SqlServer database file using Sql Server 2008 R2.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export data, create schema in sql server, import data.

Update: alternatively there are tools. Check the walkthrough at http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/migrate-a-database-to-sql-server

Comment: Thanks for answer but :
How to export data? do you mean export to a backup file? if so, can you give me the code
what do you mean about schema? explain please

Comment: Thanks,
I found an other tool,
http://www.primeworks-mobile.com/Products/DataPortWizard.html

Comment: neither the link in the answer nor the link @aEkBKF gave works anymore. does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

The chosen answer above points to a page that no longer exists. This is how I was able to achieve migrating SDF to SQL Server:
https://blog.nicolaayan.com/2018/02/how-to-migrate-sdf-database-to-sql-server/

Comment: Great answer from Nicola. The SQL Server Compact Runtime link doesn't work anymore though. You can find it here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative - I used Visual Studio 2019 with the SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox.

It provides migration to SQL Server, as well as a number of scripting options to just export schema, or just export data.

You may find, as I did, some of the rules aren't the same in SQL Server CE as they are in SQL Server. For instance, in SQL Server CE you can name a constraint to be the same name as a table. But in SQL Server, you'll get an error that the object already exists, which is easily fixable, but nothing's perfect.

[image: A picture of the SQL Lite toolbox in visual studio]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio, or if it's running select File -> Connect Object Explorer...
2. In the Connect to Server dialog change Server type to SQL Server Compact Edition
3. From the Database file drop-down select
4. Open your SDF file.

Comment: This isn't an option. Options are Database Engine, Analysis Services, Reporting Services, Integration Services. This answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason "Server Type" is unavailable in my version(s) of SQL Management Studio. After some digging around, it turns out WebMatrix offers database migration. Maybe this could help someone? :-)